# Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 error when using sharekit in ios5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm-clang

I added Sharekit in ios sdk 5.0. I even turned down the automatic reference counting for every single file present using "fno-objc-arc" I'm getting "LLVM compiler error". I have no idea what exactly the problem is. Could you guys help me out? Below is the source code link

http://www.skytel.mobi/stepheniphone/iphone/newlywed.zip

ERRORS:
1)Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 Error
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

2)UNCategorized
Build task failed without generating error messages.

Comment: Please post the errors that you are getting..

Comment: i answer a simular question maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9459077/1134766

Comment: @Nathan:i was nt able to find the option.i ve attached a source code above..cud u check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the debugger to GDB (in Product/Edit Scheme).  There seems to be some issues with LLDB and breakpoints, especially if you are breaking on all exceptions.