# Cannot compile Cocoapods with XCode/Obj-C – "Pods-prefix.pch.dia: No such file or directory"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gcc, cocoapods

I am using XCode 4.5.1 and iOS 6.0 base SDK.

Here is the error I am receiving:

`i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: /Users/fahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Currenthiphop-emodxxwwaiojlcboaxuodksuwuww/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Pods-prefix-evibdktwbatdnbabmrlnderfsxxi/Pods-prefix.pch.dia: No such file or directory`

There is only 1 file in the Pods-prefix-xxx directory:
`Pods-prefix.pch.pth.hash-criteria`

Here is my Podfile:
    platform :ios

```
pod 'LibComponentLogging-Core'
pod 'LibComponentLogging-LogFile'
pod 'LibComponentLogging-qlog' 
pod 'LibComponentLogging-pods'

pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
pod 'RestKit'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I am having this issue right now. Not sure what's going on at all.'

Comment: We're getting this error on one developer's machine, but not the rest. Doesn't matter what's specified in the podfile; Xcode refuses to build the workspace with the same error.

Answer (score 10):

I actually found [this solution right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10800989/194869) that details opening up Xcode using normal means (Finder or the Dock), as opposed to using the `open <Workspace>.xcworkspace` command. I've always used Xcode from my dock, whereas the other developer (who couldn't build the project and was getting the error you were) was using the `open` command from the command line. Once he opened Xcode from the Dock, and manually browsed to open the project that way, he could build it successfully.

Comment: Worked for me too on `OSX 10.9.2` and `cocoapods-0.32.1`! Thx

Answer (score 4):

If you are using CocoaPods 0.18.0, this might be cause by CocoaPods and is fixed in https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/956

Extra quote in "$(inherited)" was the cause (https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig.rb#L150). It should not be quoted. If you remove them from the xcconfig the project will build again. You may want to check your xcconfig and see if there are extra quote.

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be caused by a few different factors but in my case and the case of some colleagues, this resolved the missing pch.dia

Uninstall CocoaPods and install **`0.17.1`**

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.17.1 --verbose
```

Lock your Kiwi version to 2.05 if Kiwi is one of your pods:

```
target :KiwiUnitTest, :exclusive => true do
  pod 'Kiwi', '2.0.5'
```

Clean your Xcode project including Derived Data. Close down Xcode, re-open the project and build.