# Xcode 7 compilerc command failed error

Tags: ios, xcode

I just upgraded Xcode to 7.1 recently. Now I cannot compile my code. It says:

The following build commands failed:

> CompileC
>   /Users/User_Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StudywizSchool-bbmsbrwirrgkhwghtalynzbkavjz/Build/Intermediates/StudywizSchool.build/Release-iphoneos/StudywizSchool.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SWELockerItem-570C86C95F8D9976.o
>   shared/model/SWELockerItem.m normal armv7 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

While I don't know why it failed I thought llvm compiler should be higher than 1.0?  If so how could I upgrade it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457510/apple-llvm-compiler-3-1-error-clang) it may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the error is in the SWELockerItem.m file.
You can find ‘SWELockerItem.m’ keywords in the log(Cmd+F), maybe you can find the error message like this, and it's the real error =。=
[image: The Real Mistake]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work -
Change your Deployment Target and then clean and run the application.